# Get available disk space in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, driveinfo

UPDATE : I have found a solution for the iOS and Android versions, however, I'm still getting this error when building for Mac and Windows. I've seen a workaround that only gets me the name of the drives :

```
foreach (string drive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives());
```

... But that doesn't get me anywhere in terms of free space.

ORIGINAL QUESTION :

I am working in Unity C#.

I'd like to get the free available disk space on the device I'm using. I've tried using `System.IO.DriveInfo` but it doesn't work as I receive:

> NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.

...when I try to get the drives.  I think this is only a Windows problem, but I haven't found a solution doing my research.  I'm also wondering if this class will work on Android, iOS and Mac as well.

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

Why is this not working? And is there a better solution that would work on all platforms?

Comment: IMO if you shouldn't need that info in a game in the first place. When you create/modify files check that they have been properly created by responding to the corresponding exceptions. Other than that, there's probably not a common reliable solution because apps can be sandboxed (even on desktop operating systems) and thus results may not be actual disk space but for instance merely a quota reserved for the app.

Comment: Is the a Silverlight app? Or a Windows Form or Web app?

Comment: It's an app that will eventually be on all devices mentionned above (Windows standalone, Mac standalone, iOS, Android). @LearnCocos2D what would be the corresponding exceptions then ?

Comment: Quick update : my main priority right now is to get this working on Mac, was wondering if anyone had any particular pointers for this ? Do I have to use a plugin, work with XCode ? I'm in the dark here...

Comment: Why do you want this information?

Comment: the answer to "why" is obvious, say your app downloads videos or whatever - anything really.  an universal solution would be appreciated.

Comment: To check if there is enough space you should create a file with the size you need and do as CodeSlime does: Listen for an IOexception and extract an ERROR_HANDLE_DISK_FULL or ERROR_DISK_FULL from it.